# How to fix 'Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error' in C

Tags: c, gcc

I have this problem on HackerRank named "Equalize the Array", 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equality-in-a-array/problem

i have completed this program and it is working properly on my compiler but when i using the same code on the HackerRank website it is not working. 
it is showing me this error

```
GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 4647]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
#0  0x00005581998066b0 in main () at solution.c:15
15          scanf("%ld",&arr[i]);
#0  0x00005581998066b0 in main () at solution.c:15
```

and my code is :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int arr[100];
    long int n,i,j;
    long int larg=0, largno=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    long int iarr[n];
    long int max=0;
    long int out=0,fout=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%ld",&arr[i]);
}


for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    max=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[j]==arr[i])
        {
            max++;
        }
    }
    iarr[j]=max;
}


for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    if(larg < iarr[j])
    {
     larg = iarr[j];
     largno = j;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(arr[largno]==arr[i])
    {
        out++;
    }

}
fout=n-out;
printf("%ld",fout);

}
```

please help me out with this problem :)

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n)` -> `scanf("%ld",&n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate that `n` is in range [1, 99].

`scanf("%d", &n)` requires an `int` and you pass a `long`.

Verify your format strings, check the return values for errors and make sure the values are in the acceptable range.

Always compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra`, these also report format string and argument type mismatch.

Comment: there is the reverse problem at the beginning of _main_ : `scanf("%d",&n);` while _n_ is a long

Comment: IT IS STILL SHOWING THE SAME ERROR

Comment: @RudraKaniya rather than to write in uppercase GIVE US THE VALUES TO USE TO PRODUCE THE ERROR

Comment: thanks  main : scanf("%d",&n); while n is a long  this was the problem

Comment: "scanf("%ld", &arr[i]) requires a long argument, whereas you pass an int" ? _arr_ is a long

Comment: the problem was only the first scanf a priori